# How to change all files in directory creation/modification date to 0/0/0?

Tags: command-line, find, directory, date, touch

I want to change all files in directory creation/modification date to 0/0/0.

I tried to use `find $PWD -exec touch -m -d '0/0/0' {} +` command.

Comment: UNIX Epoch time starts from 01/01/1970, there is no 0/0/0.

Comment: Why is it works at 1/1/1?

Comment: What's `0/0/0` supposed to mean? There is no day/month/year 0 (while `1/1/1` does make sense).

Comment: This is dependent on file system. Some older file systems have a 32-bit time, giving ISO format 1970-01-01T00:00:00 to 2038-01-19T03:14:07. But ext4 (for example) does a huge range, but still based at 1970, so your "zero" date stores as -62167219125 seconds. TZ/DST info is a bit sparse in that era, so a few hours off can be expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is no day number 0 in a month and there is no month 0 in a year. Days and months start from 1.

Try one of these instead:

```
touch -d '1/1/0 0:0' foo
touch -t 000001010000 bar
```

Comment: I know, but I think it's possible to change creation/modification date to 0/0/0.

Comment: You thing it's possible nevertheless? This is a good start @ArianKG. Now you've got to give a meaning to a date like 0/0/0, and then to propose patches so that this meaning is understood by commands like `date`, `touch`, etc.